# Device keeps losing connection regularly when connected to Mac Mini

Tags: android, macos

I am trying to develop android apps on a MAC Mini and have installed all the required software like android SDK, eclipse and ADT.
Everything works well so far except for one thing.
I am connecting a Google Nexus phone via the USB and i have put the phone in the USB debugging mode and also have checked the option that the screen remain on while connected via USB.

But for some reason, I keep losing the connection when the device is connected at a regular interval. For ex: every 3 minutes or so. I know that it's losing connection because when I run

```
adb devices
```

after 3 minutes or so, i see no devices in the list of devices. Any workaround for this or am i not doing some set up steps correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I run into this issue as well sometimes and for me it is usually a bad port on my laptop, when I use another port than it works fine, if available try different usb ports on your computer.  Also the usb cord you are using may be faulty as well, if you have access to another cord I would try that and see if it doesn't help.

Comment: thanks. the cable is fine since i use the same on the Windows PC. I will try another USB port :) I am wondering if we are dealing with any power issues here.

Comment: power issue with the phone or laptop? It should charge the phone at the same time when it is plugged in.  That might be a good thing to check as well is if the phone charges but is not connected.  After the phone gets disconnected does it automatically reconnect or do you have to unplug and then replug in the USB cord?

Comment: It was the USB port. I had to reconnect the phone before i changed the port everytime after the connection was getting lost :) Thanks again

Answer (score 7):

I'm having the same issue on a MacBook Air and haven't found a fix. However I have an easier workaround than physically disconnecting/reconnecting the cable back and forth.

Swipe from top to bottom to show the notifications, then click on "Tap for more USB options".

[image]

Then select either MTP or PTP. The device should be reconnecting after switching between MTP and PTP.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I run into this issue as well and I've found that closing all windows that are accessing the device will resolve this issue. For example a chrome:inspect window or file browser that is accessing the device.

Sometimes I have to issue `adb kill-server` then `adb devices` after closing the windows.

Comment: You're my hero! Thanks! Never thought about it. In my case it was Stetho

Comment: It was Stetho for me too.

Answer (score 2):

i tried all the possible things which worked temporarily : 
1. reset the adb 
2.physically disconnected the usb wire and connected again 
3.changed the usb wire and used another usb port of my laptop 
4.restarted my device and mac but had to face the problem again and again . reading the above from @bwags i checked and realised that the chrome inspection window was open, after i closed it the problem resolved

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue in 2022.

Go to your phone, System->Developer Options
check all reasonable settings available.

"wait for debugger to attach" this one helped mine.

also, select your app to be the one tested, there's an options for that. quite silly.

it will ask for debugger to be attached.

M1 mac air machine with android studio Chipmonk