# Android Studio ADB connection dropping wired attached device since 2.2 on Macintosh

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, macos-sierra, android-instant-run

All of these are new for me.  It has to be one of them.

Android Studio 2.2 and Android 24.

Instant Run

Mac OS Sierra.

There doesn't seem to be any pattern.  It occurs sometimes after 2 minutes, sometimes after 10.

I have three different devices, a 4.4, a 5.0 and a 6.0+.  It's not the devices...it happens on all three.  I've been using Studio on this Mac for well over a year, and have never seen this before.

Comment: try to check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767553/device-keeps-losing-connection-regularly-when-connected-to-mac-mini). I tried the different options and solved the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look to this link: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=223114 .

It is not a permanent solution, but since the problem is that ADB disconnects, it will reconnect again.

Comment: See this.  It's widely reported.  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=219085&sort=-owner&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&start=41700

Answer (score 4):

The fix for this issue has been included in Android SDK Platform-tools 24.0.4

Comment: I'm on SDK 25 and I still can't connect to my phones, while my Mac running El Capitan can..

Comment: @jorisw This question relates to the ADB connection dropping out after being connected for a certain period. You should start a new question for your issue.

Comment: This still happens for me with platform tools 25.

Comment: This happens to me with tools 28 and High Sierra